# php post-processing publish

Tags: php, javascript, variables

I was wondering if is it possible to change an already written variable in the html generated file. Maybe there is an option to 'publish/write' the html file in the very end of php processing.

```
<html>

<?php
echo '<h1>' . $pageTitle . '</h1>';
?>

[...]

<?php
[DB queries]

$pageTitle = "New Page title";
echo "<javascript-code-to-change-the-page-title>";
?>
```

Yes I could set $pageTitle before, but it may change along the code according to some query.
So, I figure out that I can change the page title on client side only.
I'm probably missing some logic here.

Comment: Good thing to think about. 1) do all processing. 2) output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a combination of (A) PHP's Output buffering, and (B) PHP's DomDocument class.

Basically, you would capture the HTML output by wrapping the output in `ob_*` commands. Once you get the output, you throw it in the DOM parser. Once you're there, you can then traverse the DOM document and make your changes. Afterwards, you can dump everything back out to the browser.

I most definitely would not rely on JS to do any changes on the page.

ALTERNATIVELY, you could do your PHP at the top of the file, then echo the variables out as needed.

Comment: You're right. I'll do the php at the beggining and echo in the end. Thanks